# In a .Net winforms application, how do I obtain the path the current user's temp folder?

Tags: .net, winforms

Seems so basic, I can't believe I don't know this! I just need a scratch folder to dump some temporary files to. I don't care if it gets wiped out between usages or not, and I don't think I should have to go through the hassle of creating one and maintaining it myself from within my application. Is that too much to ask?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

[Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_GetFolderPath_System_Environment_SpecialFolder_)([Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2)) or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Answer (score 3):

This is for VB.NET

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
```

not sure if there's similar in C#